# Count first day of month between two dates

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql, counting

Could someone advise how I can go about counting the number of first day of month between two dates?

For example: `02/01/2015` to `05/05/2015` will count as `4`.

Comment: OK, it s little late, since there are 2 correct answer there cuurently, btw tag the one which is seems correct to use as `Answer` to help other which have the same question as you to find the answer

Answer (score 5):

It can be accomplished easily like this:

```
DECLARE @sd DATE = '02/02/2015', @ed DATE = '05/01/2015'
SELECT DATEDIFF(mm, @sd, @ed) + CASE WHEN DAY(@sd) = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
```

Answer (score 3):

If you have a sequence of dates stored somewhere (like in a calendar table) you can easily count the dates matching the `day(date)` predicate. If you don't have any suitable table with a date sequence you can use a recursive common table expression to generate one on the fly like this:

```
declare @start date 
set @start = '02/01/2015'

declare @end date 
set @end = '05/05/2015'

;with dates (date) as (
    select @start date
    union all 
    select dateadd(day, 1, date) as date from dates where date < @end
    )

select count(*) no_of_firsts from dates where day(date) = 1
```

[Sample SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d41d8/43053)